# What are accepted methods of quantifying Data Warehouse ROI?

Tags: reporting, analytics, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

**Background:**
The chief output of a data warehouse is the business decisions that are made using the warehouse. Presumably, a valuable warehouse allows a business to make decisions that are more profitable than it could have made without the warehouse.

**Context:**
Say, for example, you're trying to pitch your own company on the merits of a more comprehensive data management and analysis strategy, i.e. a data warehouse. Or, you're an ASP or consultant trying to market to businesses to build a new system or expand upon their current system. You're trying to sell decision makers - either your managers or a potential clients' - that it's worth it to invest in a data warehouse and all of the analytical and reporting tools and skillsets that come along with it.

**Question:**
What are accepted methods of quantifying this increased profitability?

Comment: Great question. I just want to add a comment that doesn't really answer you question. Besides monetary ROI, it's also a matter of ease of use. I can find a SQL whiz that can write queries against a dozen data sources, aggregate the data and produce reports and dashboards. But that's the thing, it requires a very specialized skill set. With a well designed BI infrastructure, you can produce data models that analysts and business users understand and can use to produce their own reports. Reach, ease of use, and productivity.

Answer (score 1):

You must define these params during the 1st phase prior Blueprinting....

- How often is the data loaded? Are the
- loads full upload or delta enabled.
- Archive Strategy How many users?
- Hours of operational Vs historic data?
- Mostly reporting on Detailed or summarized data?
- Information requirements?

Few more questions are like below,

- Goals of organization, unit?
- Top KPIs - What views on the KPIs do you need?
- How often do you need them?
- What sequence of drill-downs do you need?
- How are information displayed; distributed, sold
- Can everyone see everything?
- What success factors should a change in the information systems have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, It is the biggest bogeyman for BI solutions I have faced.

The basic focus of BI/DW is on the KPIs (Key Performance Indicators) of an industry and how measuring/monitoring/analysis of the same can lead to better management decisions that 'optimize' these KPIs. (KPIs - eg Turn around Time, number of sales etc etc etc)

Sad part is, till you haven't implemented these, you dont know the average %ROI on these KPIs. The solutions we have used in start is to quote industry reports for DW/BI (the industry specific) implementations when you pitch in for the first time. Hopefully if you then launch your product, the DW tool itself measures its ROI over time by tracking the improvements over these KPIs.

Do keep that in mind when you design the DW, you need to get those measurements for the next time! For your next sale, nothing sells like ROIs measured from your previous DW implementations :)

ps -

There are other soft sells too - the pointers listed by @openingbrace.

Answer (score 0):

Good question @Emre.

With our clients, we are always asked to come in when a decision has already been made to proceed with a DWH; so justification is not necessary, though we have been asked to examine ROI after the fact sometimes to justify the project!

Following on from @Jai's comment, even with a set of KPI's/dashboard that is well chosen/designed, unless there is a business culture that can accept/implement actions from KPIs, the ROI will be diffcult to see. Im not sure that there will be average %ROI on specific KPI's unfortunately, as this is too dependent on industry/country/culture/economic conditions.

The easiest way we have been able to show ROI on DWH projects, is procedural improvement. Mostly this is around report execution efficiencies.

- Find out current man-hours to run reports - some of our clients had reports run through linked excel workbooks that take a number of man-days(!) to produce.
- reproduce reports in the DWH
- See what the man-hours saved

This is the easiest tangible (£) benefit to be gained, and a few of our DWH projects have been completely paid for by the wages saved on report generation.

I also like @OpeningBrace's lists, but these will be difficult to get hard %ROI figures from them.